# Unable to write a Macro for Excel VBA to copy a specific cell value to the next blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a value followed by exactly 29 spaces. I am trying to find a way to copy that value to the next 29 blank row spaces then loop again and copy the next value to the following 29 spaces.

Each value is different and there is no sequential order. I have over 50,000 rows and I have spent so much time trying to find a way to do this. Any help is much appreciated. I believe I can run a loop to accomplish this however I am a newb. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please clarify a couple of points, because I'm not clear on the question; when you say "followed by exactly 29 spaces" do you mean that you have 29 empty cells below each value, and that the following value will be in the cell 30 rows below the original one?

Comment: And where is the "next value" that you want copied to the next 29 "spaces"/blank cells?  And please show us what you already have or already have tried.

Comment: Sorry by spaces I did mean 29 cells and the value will be in the following 29 cells creating 30 cells of the same value. I am only trying to affect column A. I tried some random copy paste formulas but I could never figure out how to get the code to loop again starting from the next value and to continue until it reaches a specific cell. I hope this helps. I am good with HTML and CSS but am still learning VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you where you need to go. Post again with details if you run into any problems with it:

```
Sub Copy29Rows()

Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng_Source As Excel.Range, rng_target As Excel.Range

'Change this to the name of the worksheet that you're working with
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Change the sheet and cell name to whatever your original source is.
Set rng_Source = wks.Range("A1")

'Check that there is a value to copy
If rng_Source.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "There are no values to copy"
    GoTo ExitPoint
End If

'We keep looping until we find no further values.
Do While rng_Source.Value <> ""

    'Make sure that you don't run off the end of the sheet
    If rng_Source.Row + 29 > wks.Rows.Count Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 20000, , "There aren't enough empty rows in the sheet to copy down 29 rows."
    End If

    'The target will be offset one row from the value that we're
    'copying and will be 29 rows high.
    Set rng_target = rng_Source.Offset(1, 0).Resize(29, rng_Source.Columns.Count)

    'Now copy the original value and paste it into the target range
    rng_Source.Copy rng_target

    'Finally move the source 30 rows down.
    Set rng_Source = rng_Source.Offset(30, 0)

Loop

ExitPoint:
On Error Resume Next
Set rng_Source = Nothing
Set rng_target = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Comment: The code gave me an error of Compile error: Expected End Sub. Is it something I did? I replaced Sheet2 with my worksheet name and A1 with my beginning source of cell A3303. Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Make sure that you copied ALL of the code. There's an End Sub right at the bottom which is easy to miss out on copying if you don't scroll all the way down in the code block. I just copied the whole thing and pasted it into a new module in  Excel (to make sure that I didn't lose anything when I posted it) and it compiles OK

Comment: You sir are a computer god. I dream of possessing the skills you do. Thanks for your help. You saved me hours of tedious work and for that I am grateful.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I was wondering about that but I found the answer check. I tried to give it a good reputation but I don't have enough skills. Hopefully I will soon. I am already breaking down the answer to learn more VBA.