# Transpose a single column to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have one column of data with approximately 800 records. Each 18 cells is one record.  I need a script that takes every 18 cells and transposes them to a row dynamically, or even a way to write excel formula to transpose every 18 records from the column to a row.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We love to help people, but we must see what you have tried. This proves that you have a problem and are not here just to get some copy-paste code.

Comment: If your data starts in A1 then in B1 enter: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),18)=1,OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-2,0),"")` Fill the formula over to fill 18 columns, and then down to cover your 800 rows.

Comment: Tim's idea is an elegant one and should work, though I'll admit that I'd be reluctant to use a formula based solution for something like this where 800 rows are involved. Depends on the speed of your PC but I find that lookup-like formulas tend to grind in Excel if you throw a lot at it. If you go this path I'd be inclined to do the calculation once, copy the formula block and paste as values.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get asked "what have you tried" since it's preferred that you have a bash at it and ask when you get stuck rather than asking for a complete solution. That having been said, I can offer you some tips to get you started.

To do this in VBA you need to perform a loop which starts at the first cell, gets a range consisting of that cell and the following 18 rows, then pastes that into (probably) another sheet in the workbook, transposing it from a column to a row. The loop will then offset 19 cells and start again.

Take a look at the answer that I gave in this thread:
[Unable to write a Macro for Excel VBA to copy a specific cell value to the next blank rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545064/unable-to-write-a-macro-for-excel-vba-to-copy-a-specific-cell-value-to-the-next/13545315#13545315)

That will give you the syntax for doing a loop which is somewhat similar to yours.

To get the syntax for doing a paste / transpose, do it manually and record your actions using the macro recorder. That can be found on the Developer tab. (If you don't have the Developer tab visible, go to File -> Options -> Customise Ribbon and turn on the Developer tab there.)

Give it a try, and if you find that you can't quite make it work just post again with the details of where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this VBA code to achieve this .

```
    Public Sub TransposePaste()
   'Value we want to step by....
    Dim stepVal As Long
    stepVal = 18
'Declare start row variable (-1)
 Dim row As Long
 row = 0

'Declare the column the data is coming from
Dim col As Long
col = 1

'Declare and set worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

'end row of the data
Dim endRow As Long


endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row

'cycle to end of data end of data...
For i = 1 To endRow Step stepVal

'increment row each time
row = row + 1

    'cycle through the columns outputting the data
    For j = 1 To stepVal

    Sheet1.Cells(row, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + j - 1, col).Value

    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub